# SBCL Compile Error & Warning about a Conflict with Type base-char

Tags: arrays, char, typeerror, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to optimize a function by changing an argument from type `string` to `simple-base-string` (among other things). But this produces a compiler error:

```
(declaim (ftype (function (simple-base-string) (or nil t)) dictionary-compatible))
(defun dictionary-compatible ($new-cross-str)  ;eg, "A?R??" of length 5
  "Tests if a string (with uppercase alphabetic and ? characters)
   is compatible with the dictionary words (symbols) in a hash-table."
  (declare (optimize (speed 3)))
  (iter (with len = (length $new-cross-str))
        (declare (fixnum len))
        (for chr in-vector $new-cross-str)
        (declare (base-char chr))
        (for index from 0)
        (declare (fixnum index))
        (when (char/= chr #\?)
          (collect (gethash (format nil "~D~C~D" len chr index)
                            *lci-dictionary*) into dict-words))
        (finally (return (reduce #'intersection dict-words)))))


; in: DEFUN DICTIONARY-COMPATIBLE
;     (ITERATE:ITER
;       (ITERATE:WITH WOULDWORK-PKG::LEN = (LENGTH WOULDWORK-PKG::$NEW-CROSS-STR))
;       (DECLARE (FIXNUM WOULDWORK-PKG::LEN))
;       (ITERATE:FOR WOULDWORK-PKG::CHR WOULDWORK-PKG::IN-VECTOR
;        WOULDWORK-PKG::$NEW-CROSS-STR)
;       (DECLARE (BASE-CHAR WOULDWORK-PKG::CHR))
;       (ITERATE:FOR WOULDWORK-PKG::INDEX WOULDWORK-PKG::FROM 0)
;       (DECLARE (FIXNUM WOULDWORK-PKG::INDEX))
;       (WHEN (CHAR/= WOULDWORK-PKG::CHR #\?)
;         (ITERATE:COLLECT
;          (GETHASH
;           (FORMAT NIL "~D~C~D" WOULDWORK-PKG::LEN WOULDWORK-PKG::CHR
;                   WOULDWORK-PKG::INDEX)
;           WOULDWORK-PKG::*LCI-DICTIONARY*)
;          WOULDWORK-PKG::INTO WOULDWORK-PKG::DICT-WORDS))
;       (ITERATE:FINALLY
;        (RETURN (REDUCE #'INTERSECTION WOULDWORK-PKG::DICT-WORDS))))
; --> BLOCK BLOCK TAGBODY PROGN IF PROGN
; ==>
;   WOULDWORK-PKG::DICT-WORDS
;
; note: deleting unreachable code
;
; caught WARNING:
;   Constant NIL conflicts with its asserted type BASE-CHAR.
;   See also:
;     The SBCL Manual, Node "Handling of Types"
```

Does the macroexpansion of the `iter` statement offer any clues to the problem(s)?

```
* (macroexpand-1 '(iter (with len = (length $new-cross-str))
        (declare (fixnum len))
        (for chr in-vector $new-cross-str)
        (declare (base-char chr))
        (for index from 0)
        (declare (fixnum index))
        (when (char/= chr #\?)
          (collect (gethash (format nil "~D~C~D" len chr index)
                            *lci-dictionary*) into dict-words))
        (finally (return (reduce #'intersection dict-words)))))
(LET* ((LEN (THE FIXNUM (LENGTH $NEW-CROSS-STR)))
       (#:SEQUENCE414 NIL)
       (#:LIMIT415 NIL)
       (CHR NIL)
       (#:INDEX413 NIL)
       (INDEX 0)
       (DICT-WORDS NIL)
       (#:END-POINTER416 NIL)
       (#:TEMP417 NIL))
  (DECLARE (FIXNUM LEN))
  (DECLARE (BASE-CHAR CHR))
  (DECLARE (FIXNUM INDEX))
  (BLOCK NIL
    (BLOCK #:ITERATE142
      (TAGBODY
        (PROGN (SETQ #:SEQUENCE414 $NEW-CROSS-STR) (SETQ #:LIMIT415 (LENGTH #:SEQUENCE414)) (SETQ #:INDEX413 -1) (SETQ INDEX -1))
       LOOP-TOP-NIL
        (PROGN
         (SETQ #:INDEX413 (+ #:INDEX413 1))
         (IF (>= #:INDEX413 #:LIMIT415)
             (GO LOOP-END-NIL))
         (SETQ CHR (AREF #:SEQUENCE414 #:INDEX413))
         (SETQ INDEX (+ INDEX 1))
         (IF (CHAR/= CHR #\?)
             (PROGN
              (SETQ #:TEMP417 (LIST (GETHASH (FORMAT NIL "~D~C~D" LEN CHR INDEX) *LCI-DICTIONARY*)))
              (SETQ #:END-POINTER416
                      (IF DICT-WORDS
                          (SETF (CDR #:END-POINTER416) #:TEMP417)
                          (SETQ DICT-WORDS #:TEMP417)))
              DICT-WORDS)))
        (PROGN)
        (GO LOOP-TOP-NIL)
       LOOP-END-NIL
        (PROGN (RETURN (REDUCE #'INTERSECTION DICT-WORDS))))
      NIL)))
T
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `iterate` which is fairly common (`series` had it, long ago, as well).  The problem is that it binds your `chr` variable too early, and in particular before it has worked out that it can bind it to the first element of the vector (because the vector might not *have* any elements).  So it needs to find some default value ... and picks `nil`, which is not correct.

This is sometimes hard to avoid: in the `series` case I think there were clearly cases where it was difficult to deal with.  This is not one of those.

A horrid workaround is to declare types as `(or null <type-you-want>)`.  `loop` also gets this right in SBCL (by, if it has to, turning the type declaration in something like `(loop ... for x of-type fosh across ... ...)` into `(or null fosh)`).  This is better than not working at all, but it does mean that the type declaration for the variable is not what you expect it to be by looking at the code, so in particular something like `(loop for x of-type fosh across ... do (setq x nil) ...)` will not be picked up as an error.

---

As a note: this is why I avoid complicated iteration constructs: they almost always have obscure bugs like this.  `loop` probably has had most of them sorted out by now if you can bear it (I can't).

Comment: I'm reluctantly coming to believe that time spent on specialized declarative optimizations, in general, is a red herring. Mostly the timing seems comparable or even slightly worse than no declarations at all. However, they evidently do allow the compiler to catch more programming bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Looking closely to [§Types and Declarations](https://iterate.common-lisp.dev/doc/Types-and-Declarations.html#Types-and-Declarations) in the documentation, iterate is well aware of the problem of initializing iterating variables properly, and tries to detect which type is the best for a counter and which initial value in that type should be assigned initially; this is based on `the` expressions or the kind of iterators being used. Note also that if you add `(declare (iterate:declare-variables))`, type declarations will be added automatically (this is disabled by default, this can be switched globally using a special variable).

For example, it is possible to iterate using `in-string`:

```
(iterate:iter (iter:for el in-string word)
  (declare (character el))
  (iter:counting (alpha-char-p el)))
```

Here the type will be `character`, and the default value will be character `#\Nul`. Alternatively, if we use `the` expression around `el`, we can narrow the type to `base-char`:

```
(iter:iter (iter:for (the base-char el) in-string word)
  (declare (iterate:declare-variables))
  (iter:counting (alpha-char-p el)))
```

This is how it appears once expanded:

```
(LET* ((#:SEQUENCE47 "") (#:LIMIT48 0) (EL #\Nul) (#:INDEX46 0) (#:RESULT45 0))
  (DECLARE (TYPE FIXNUM #:RESULT45)
           (TYPE FIXNUM #:INDEX46)
           (TYPE BASE-CHAR EL)
           (TYPE FIXNUM #:LIMIT48)
           (TYPE STRING #:SEQUENCE47))
  (DECLARE (ITERATE:DECLARE-VARIABLES))
  (BLOCK NIL
    (BLOCK #:ITERATE1215
      (TAGBODY
        (PROGN
         (SETQ #:SEQUENCE47 WORD)
         (SETQ #:LIMIT48 (LENGTH #:SEQUENCE47))
         (SETQ #:INDEX46 -1))
       LOOP-TOP-NIL
        (PROGN
         (SETQ #:INDEX46 (+ #:INDEX46 1))
         (IF (>= #:INDEX46 #:LIMIT48)
             (GO LOOP-END-NIL))
         (SETQ EL (CHAR #:SEQUENCE47 #:INDEX46))
         (IF (ALPHA-CHAR-P EL)
             (SETQ #:RESULT45 (1+ #:RESULT45))
             #:RESULT45))
        (PROGN)
        (GO LOOP-TOP-NIL)
       LOOP-END-NIL
        (PROGN))
      #:RESULT45)))
```

Comment: The trouble is that the whole problem it is trying to solve is of its own making.  It (and loop) could easily have had expansions which look like `(let ((secret-iteration-variable ...)) (tagbody ... (let ((user-variable secret-iteration-variable)) ... user declarations and code ...) ... (go ...) ...))` but chose not to.